# PHP writing html to a php page from a field in database

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm relatively new to this and am familiar with echo in PHP but what I need is to have the contents of a field in a database to be placed in the page (but not as a written field)

For example

```
<?php echo $product_description['description']; ?>
```

the field description has html formating in it already so when I use 'echo' it writes out for example

```
<p>text on firstline <br> text on next line
```

And what I want is that this html from this field in the database that already has html formating to simply placed in the php page which would make it look like this

text on firstline 
 text on next line

I assume I just need to use a different command than ECHO but don't know which one.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve, can you explain what have you tried and what result you expecting?

Comment: Not to be obvious but are you connecting to the database?

Comment: if you want to run html code you can use : echo nl2br($html); but if you want to show your html code you can use :<code> or htmlspecialchars($html)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
echo html_entity_decode($product_description["description"]);
```

If that works, the HTML in your database has been encoded using htmlentities, so you must decode it to write to a page.

Comment: If anything OP should use `htmlspecialchars()` :-)

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH!  THIS WAS PERFECT!

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags is what you're after.

Use it like so: `echo strip_tags($your database bit to echo here);`
[PHP docs for strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)